# Select the content of a <script>...</script> as plain text within the html body?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so lets say i have this here:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mySecondScript.js">
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainScriptContainer">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer('jwplayer-0').setup({
    "image": "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/hHbAEl1Wbms/0.jpg",
    "file": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHbAEl1Wbms"
    });
  </script>
</div>
</body>
```

And all I want to do (within "mySecondScript.js" placed in the header) is to select as plain text the entire content of the `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` and contain it inside a variable.

I'll try to explain even further with an example of what I could do with it and what effect it should have

function(){
  var plainText = ;//here goes the function that select the whole script content witch is itself contained within the 
  alert(plainText);
};

And this would create an alert saying:

```
jwplayer('jwplayer-0').setup({"image": "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/hHbAEl1Wbms/0.jpg", "file": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHbAEl1Wbms"});
```

The function can be in Javascript or jQuery, it doesn't matter

Comment: You're missing `</script>` on your first script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that script tag's text by using the `.text()` function. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to know more about `.text()`

Try,

```
$(function(){
   var plainText = $('.mainScriptContainer script').text();
   alert(plainText);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/a99Ln/)

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier if you have problems with `.text()` in some browsers you can do `elm.text()||elm.html()`. I know there was a problem - I think with some IE versions - where you had to use `html()`.

Comment: @t.niese I don't think so. can you name some browsers which don't support `.text()` ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I can't test right now. But for IE 6 i know that `.text()` did not work. And I thought that it is the same for IE 7. And for IE 8 if it is in not in standartmode.

Answer (score 1):

`<script>` elements are element nodes in the DOM, so you can get them like this:

```
document
    .getElementsByClassName('mainScriptContainer')[0]
    .getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
```

And then, to get its inner text, you can use

- [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)
- [`.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild)[`.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue)
- [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)